# How to get order by with inner query

Tags: sql

```
select 
    * 
from emp 
where id 
    (select order
    from department
    where name = 'testing'
    order by order asc)
```

I am getting ordered data from the inner query and with the id's I get I should get the result from the emp table to be in the same order as the inner query.

Comment: I think you've dropped an `in` between `id` and `(`. This would be better done as an inner join rather than a subquery - would that be a reasonable change? The only way to deterministically determine the order of the results from a query is to have an `ORDER BY` on the outermost `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is order by clause allowed in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101908/is-order-by-clause-allowed-in-a-subquery)

Answer (score 2):

If it's reasonable to re-write your query as a join:

```
select e.*
from emp e
inner join department d
    on e.id = d.order
where d.name = 'testing'
order by d.order asc
```

Where this would change your results is if there are multiple rows in `department` with the same `order` value matching one or more rows in `emp` - in which case *this* query will return multiple rows, whereas the original would not. But if such a condition doesn't apply, then this is the query I'd recommend.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I don't have any relationship set between dept and emp tables. will this work in this case?? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Vijay - yes, that would be fine. SQL allows you to write arbitrary join conditions between tables - you don't have to only follow defined foreign keys.

Comment: You miss `where` clause, but answer is pretty OK

Comment: @veljasije - what `where` clause? - the only `where` clause in the original question isn't required because it's covered by the `ON` for the `JOIN`

Comment: I mean `Where name = 'testing'`

Comment: @veljasije - ah, yes. sorry. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Damien's answer is quite cool and perfect. but if you still want to go with subquery then try this

```
select * 
from emp 
where id in (select order from department where name = 'testing' order by order asc) 
order by id asc
```

May this help you

Comment: Thanks!! vikash-singh but i want order to be in the order column of department not based on the emp id. is that acheivable?.

Comment: then use **group by id** in place of *order by id*.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the right number of rows in case there more than 1 match between emp.id and department.order

```
select * from emp e
where exists
(select 1 from department d where d.name = 'testing' 
and e.id = d.order1) -- order is a reserved word in several sql languages
order by id
```

It seems there is something funny going on between your tables. Would would department contain any information about emp(I assume it is employee table) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that there is an actual temporary table with the inner query and that it is sorted and processed in a certain way. However, you can sort the outer query by emp.id.

```
select * from emp where id in 
     (select order from department where name = 'testing')
order by id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.* from emp as e, department d where e.id=d.order and d.name='testing' order by d.order
```