# Get most recent records from the table if a 'ALERT' status is present otherwise most recent record with 'OK' Status - Mysql v5.6.50

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

In Mysql I have the following table - `property_alert_status` having columns :

```
id (primary), propertyId, status, updatedAt
```

All record - `select * from property_alert_status`

| id | propertyId | status | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ALERT | 1658304031 |
| 2 | 2 | OK | 1658300273 |
| 3 | 3 | ALERT | 1658312336 |
| 4 | 3 | ALERT | 1658313979 |
| 5 | 3 | OK | 1658312336 |
| 6 | 2 | OK | 1658312336 |

From the above table, I want to fetch the most recent record for the  property based on status. If Status is 'ALERT' then most recent 'ALERT' record otherwise Most recent 'OK' record.

Ex - For propertyId '3' there are three records but most recent alert status is of id 4 so the output for the above propertyId 3 should be:

| id | propertyId | status | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | ALERT | 1658313979 |

Expected Output should be:

| id | propertyId | status | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ALERT | 1658304031 |
| 4 | 3 | ALERT | 1658313979 |
| 6 | 2 | OK | 1658312336 |

I have made one query but the output is not as expected:

```
Select mainStatus.* from (
SELECT *
FROM property_alert_status
ORDER BY
(CASE
    WHEN status = "ALERT" THEN 0
    ELSE 1
END) ASC, updatedAt DESC
) mainStatus group by  propertyId;
```

Innerquery is giving the right result but when selecting only a single record by grouping propertyId, giving the wrong result.

Inner query giving result:

| id | propertyId | status | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | ALERT | 1658313979 |
| 3 | 3 | ALERT | 1658312336 |
| 1 | 1 | ALERT | 1658304031 |
| 5 | 3 | OK | 1658312336 |
| 6 | 2 | OK | 1658312336 |
| 2 | 2 | OK | 1658300273 |

The final query gives result:

| id | propertyId | status | updatedAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ALERT | 1658304031 |
| 2 | 2 | OK | 1658300273 |
| 3 | 3 | ALERT | 1658312236 |

***Note***: Using Mysql v5.6.50.

Comment: Next time [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy the data as formatted text into your request instead.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have updated my question as suggested.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: It's good you added that but clearly you have not given a [mre], per my comment & its links. Also you haven't followed the rest of what I commented. PS [Is order by clause allowed in a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2101908/3404097) [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/3404097) [tour] PS Your post does not ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By combining my query with some changes into the @Thorsten Kettner's query -

Following Query giving expected result:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   property_alert_status s
WHERE
   id = (SELECT
           s2.id
       FROM
           property_alert_status s2
       WHERE
           s2.propertyId = s.propertyId
       ORDER BY (CASE
           WHEN s2.status = 'ALERT' THEN 0
           ELSE 1
       END) ASC, s2.updatedAt DESC
       LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tables in SQL are unordered data set. A query result is a table. So the `ORDER BY` clause in your subquery doesn't have to sort the rows. Don't rely on it. Some DBMS even raise an error when you have an `ORDER BY` at the end of a subquery.

Moreover, `select * from ... group by ...` is invalid. If you group by a column, you can select that column plus aggregates, i.e. sums, maximums, averages and so on. You cannot select other original column values (except for the case they are functionally dependent on your group, such as a person's name when you group by the person's ID). MySQL should raise an error, and if it doesn't, this probably means that you are working in a cheat mode that MySQL invented in their early days. Make sure to always `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` when working with MySQL in order to have the DBMS help you with invalid aggregation queries.

As to the task: You can rank your rows with `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    s.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid ORDER BY status, updatedat DESC) AS rn
  FROM vk_property_temperature_alert_status s
  WHERE temperature_status IN ('ALERT', 'OK')
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

For old MySQL versions I see two approaches. Either select only those rows for which not exists a better row or select those rows that are the best for their group. The second approach seems easier. It's basically writing a subquery that determines the top row for the property ID, so you can check whether the row you are looking at is a top row.

```
SELECT *
FROM vk_property_temperature_alert_status s
WHERE id =
(
  SELECT s2.id
  FROM vk_property_temperature_alert_status s2
  WHERE s2.temperature_status IN ('ALERT', 'OK')
  AND s2.propertyid = s.propertyid
  ORDER BY s2.status, s2.updatedat DESC
  LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyid ORDER BY status, updatedat DESC) AS rn

line throwing an error "( is not valid at this position for this server version expecting FOR, LOCK, SELECCT"

I think it does not exist in mysql.

Comment: Maybe you are using a very old MySQL version. You need MySQL 8 for this.

Comment: Mysql version is 5.6. can not upgrade as the project requirement.

Comment: I am sorry to hear you must work with such an old version. This forces you to write queries sometimes that are less straight-forward and thus harder to mainain and/or more error-prone. In your case, though, the old-fashioned query is not to complex. It may be a tad slow, but has good readability in my opinion. I've added it to my answer. You can add `AND temperature_status IN ('ALERT', 'OK')` to the main query's `WHERE` clause, which looks a bit superfluous, but may speed up access.

Comment: Bravo!!!! @ThorstenKettner. A vote up there.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner by changing some in your query it worked.
basically, I combined your query with mine (as mentioned in the question itself) and it is working perfectly fine. Mentioned in the answer. Thanks a lot to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, wrote just for fun as the question was very interesting:

```
SELECT 
MAX(maxId),
propertyId,
`status`,
MAX(dates) updatedAt
FROM
( 
SELECT 
firstResult.*,
(CASE WHEN @running_propertyId=0 THEN @running_propertyId:=propertyId ELSE @running_propertyId:=@running_propertyId END) runningPro,
(CASE WHEN @running_status='' THEN @running_status:=`status` ELSE @running_status:=@running_status END) runningStat,
(CASE WHEN  @running_variable >0 AND @running_propertyId =propertyId   THEN  @running_variable:=@running_variable+1 ELSE @running_variable:=1 END )var,

(CASE WHEN  @running_variable =1    THEN  @running_date:=updatedAt ELSE (CASE WHEN  `status`='ALERT' THEN @running_date:=updatedAt ELSE 
   ( CASE WHEN @running_status=`status` THEN @running_date:=updatedAt ELSE @running_date:=@running_date END) END) END )dates,

(CASE WHEN  @running_variable =1    THEN  @running_id:=id ELSE (CASE WHEN  `status`='ALERT' THEN @running_id:=id ELSE 
( CASE WHEN @running_status=`status` THEN @running_id:=id ELSE @running_id:=@running_id END) END) END )maxId,


@running_propertyId:=propertyId,
@running_status:=`status`
FROM (SELECT 
   a.*,
   @running_propertyId:=0,
   @running_status:='',
   @running_variable:=0,
   @running_date:=0,
   
   @running_id:=0
  FROM
    property_alert_status a 
 ORDER BY 
 `propertyId`
 ,`updatedAt`) firstResult
  ) final
  GROUP BY  propertyId
```

Comment: It is failing in case of record id-3 for propertyId-3 is updated recently. so instead of giving result id-3 propertyId-3  status-ALERT it is giving id-5 propertyId-3  status-OK

Comment: It looks a bit masochistic to me to write a MySQL query with variables "just for fun" :D

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry bro, I didn’t get you

Comment: Sorry, it's just a joke. I, too, enjoy puzzles. But when it comes to MySQL queries dealing with variables, it stops being enjoyable to me.

Comment: Yeah, I too started this query thinking it was not too difficult. It got me scratching my head for over an hour